# ZkCli state stay on Connecting no Connected

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I have an issue, starting my zkServer is working well but when i do

```
sudo bin/zkCli.sh
```

It displayed the follow for hours:

```
Connecting to localhost:2181
Welcome to ZooKeeper!
JLine support is enabled
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTING) 0]
```

if i tried

```
ls /
```

it will show (i don't think that's the issue as it is not connected):

```
Exception in thread "main" 
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /
at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getData(ZooKeeper.java:1212)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getData(ZooKeeper.java:1241)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain.processZKCmd(ZooKeeperMain.java:725)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain.processCmd(ZooKeeperMain.java:599)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain.run(ZooKeeperMain.java:362)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain.main(ZooKeeperMain.java:290)
```

Comment: can this be reproduced ? try `echo srvr |nc localhost 2181`

Comment: Check the log/zookeeper.out. Edit conf/zoo.cfg to reflect your IP address.

Comment: echo srvr tell me This Zookeeper instance is not currently serving requests

Comment: @PilouPierre-LouisChevallier so you are trying to setup a cluster, not a standalone node? check the other zk nodes, the election is not done, so zk is no serving.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue. For me the zookeeper hadn't started. 
Before my fix, when I did `zkcli -server localhost:2181`, I got

```
Connecting to localhost:2181
Welcome to ZooKeeper!
JLine support is enabled
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTING) 0]
```

like you. Notice the "CONNECTING" here. Doing `ls /` here gave error and exited zkcli:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /
at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:102)
at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:54)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getChildren(ZooKeeper.java:1541)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getChildren(ZooKeeper.java:1569)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain.processZKCmd(ZooKeeperMain.java:732)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain.processCmd(ZooKeeperMain.java:600)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain.executeLine(ZooKeeperMain.java:372)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain.run(ZooKeeperMain.java:332)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain.main(ZooKeeperMain.java:291)
```

The fix is is to start your zookeeper using `zkServer start`
On running this, you get:

```
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /usr/local/etc/zookeeper/zoo.cfg
Starting zookeeper ... STARTED
```

After this when you do `zkcli -server localhost:2181`, you get:

```
Connecting to localhost:2181
Welcome to ZooKeeper!
JLine support is enabled

WATCHER::

WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 0] ls /
[cf, zookeeper]
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 1]
```

Notice the 'CONNECTED' here.  I had created /cf after successful connection. 

 Hope this solution helps.

 For mac users, your `zkServer` is in `usr/local/Cellar/zookeeper/3.4.13/bin`